# How can I connect from container(API) to container(elasticsearch)?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have 2 container.One of them is web API and other is elasticsearch.
When I up API in local machine(without container) and 
       up elasticsearch in docker container.I can index data to elasticsearch its runnig good and connection url to elasticsearch such http://localhost:9200 there is no problem.

But When I want to up API with docker container and elasticsearch with docker container there is some problem I cant index data to elasticsearch with same connection url such http://localhost:9200

so I think problem is about connection url, But I m not sure .My docker compose like below.

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
       - "8080:80"
      network : 
        - host
      container_name : DataCollectorAPI
    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
          - "9300:9300"
        environment:
          - discovery.type=single-node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link the container, like this

```
web:
    ....
    links:
     - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
     - elasticsearch
```

Then from your web container use `elasticsearch` as a hostname.

See the [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) documentation for details.

Also you can just directly use the other container name as hostname

> Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the case - docker-compose will create default network so there is no need for using `link` option, moreover it is deprecated docker feature see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links). And `depends_on` option is used to launch containers in given order for example - see [depends_on docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on). However `depends_on` could be used here to express that elasticsearch should be launched before `web` container - but the problem in this question was networking.

Answer (score 1):

> But When I want to up API with docker container and elasticsearch with docker container there is some problem I cant index data to elasticsearch with same connection url such http://localhost:9200

If you want to access `elasticsearch` container from your `web` container you should use url `elasticsearch:9200`. By default docker-compose will create a network for services defined inside it and all containers will join this network with DNS names as their names in docker-compose. When you are using `http://localhost:9200` from `web` container you are trying to access `localhost` of `web` container - not elasticsearch one.