# Elasticsearch logging with NLog fails in ASP Net Core API

Tags: api, docker, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nlog

I making some tests for logging into an Elasticsearch instance using NLog in our API. The Elasticsearch instance is running inside a Docker, if the API is executed using IIS Express I can log into Elasticsearch without a problem and I can look at the "logstash" index created, but if I run the API inside a Docker container the logs never reach Elasticsearch and the index is never created.

My NLog config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore3.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="ElasticSearch" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"/>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ElasticSearch" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And in my appsettings.json:

```
"ElasticsearchUrl": "http://192.168.0.9:9200",
```

Perhaps I'm missing something or I'm not understanding the interaction between the containers.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414669/how-can-i-connect-from-containerapi-to-containerelasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your question doesn't provide any details about the configuration of the two containers (one running your app, one running Elasticsearch).

I have an example logging to Elasticsearch, configured with Kibana to view the results, although it uses a different logger provider (Essential.LoggerProvider.Elasticsearch), however it has a docker-compose file that shows the connection between Elasticsearch and Kibana, https://github.com/sgryphon/essential-logging/tree/master/examples/HelloElasticsearch

```
# Docker Compose file for E-K stack
# Run with:
# docker-compose up -d

version: '3.7'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.6.1
    ...
    networks:
      - elastic-network

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:7.6.1
    ...
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - elastic-network

networks:
  elastic-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The relevant parts show setting up a network bridge between the two docker machines, and then the connection between them.

While "http://192.168.0.9:9200" might be the correct connection from outside (your IIS) into Elasticsearch, you would have to check if it is how your API docker sees the Elasticsearch machine, e.g. how Kibana sees Elasticsearch in the example above is "http://elasticsearch:9200"

You would need to update the question with details of your docker configuration, e.g. the command line you run to start them, or a docker compose file, etc. to work out why they can't see each other.

(2) You might want to check that it really is working from IIS, as it seems unusual that NLog would create an index "logstash-" ... normally Logstash would create that index and NLog should create it's own, e.g. log4net creates index "log-", Essential.LoggerProvider.Elasticsearch uses "dotnet-", etc.

**Disclaimer: I am the author of Essential.LoggerProvider.Elasticsearch**