# .NET Core log with Nlog.Target.ElasticSearch inside Docker container does not work

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, nlog

I have been working on this problem since a lot of time and I don't understand why am I still not able to see logs in ElasticSearch using NLog.

**Stack:**

- .NET Core Application
- Docker Container
- Logging with NLog
- Nlog targeting ElasticSearch thanks to https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/wiki

**Code:**

Here is my configuration :

- NLog.Config

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="${basedir}//internal-nlog.txt">

  <variable name="appName" value="MY_APP"/>
  <include file="NLogWebFormat.config"/>
  <include file="NLogCommon.config"/>
</nlog>
```

- NLogCommon.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="ElasticSearchTargetLogs, ConsoleTarget" minlevel="Information"/>
  </rules>

  <targets>
    <default-wrapper xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
      <wrapper-target xsi:type="RetryingWrapper"/>
    </default-wrapper>

      
    <!-- Elastic loggers -->
    <target name="ElasticSearchTargetLogs" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
        <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" uri="${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.ElasticSearch}"
                index="${configsetting:item=ApplicationConfiguration.EnvironmentName}-MY_APP.logs-${date:format=yyyyMM}"
                layout="${defaultLayout}" includeAllProperties="true"
                requireAuth="true"
                username="${configsetting:item=ElasticSearchConfiguration.Login}"
                password="${configsetting:item=ElasticSearchConfiguration.Password}"
                disableCertificateValidation="true">
            <field name="AppName" layout="${appName}" />
            <field name="ExceptionType" layout="${exception:format=Type}" />
            <field name="Logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <field name="Leveltext" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
            <field name="ThreadId" layout="${threadid}" />
            <field name="RequestID" layout="${aspnet-item:variable=requestID}" />   
            <field name="data" layout="${message}" />
        </target>
    </target>
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
            name="ConsoleTarget"
            encoding="utf-8"
            layout="${defaultLayout}" />
  </targets>
</nlog>
```

**Problem:**

I can see logs in console when I test the app so logs are working well. I suppose the problem is in the connection with Elastic Search.

BUT I don't know what I have forgotten and I have no logs of what is failing.
Anyone has any idea ?

PS: I have no user/password for ES in local but I have some in production. That's why I am using these properties in the config

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414669/how-can-i-connect-from-containerapi-to-containerelasticsearch ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60898070/193178 ?

Comment: I've checked these two topics but none of them is related to my problem it seems